# node-xmpp build fails on windows 7

Tags: c++, node.js, build, visual-studio-2013, npm

I'm trying to `npm install -g node-xmpp` and the build fails on the c++ compilation part with the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib' [C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-xmpp\node_modules\node-expat\build\node_expat.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\shon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-xmpp\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

---

I've tried removing and re-installing all my visual studio components, with no luck (**currently using VS 2013 express**).

if I look at the environment vars on visual studio command prompt, I can see that **windowssdkdir** points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\ and kernel32.lib is there at the Lib dir.

I'm lost, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What command line is being passed to the linker?

Comment: Maybe try opening C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-xmpp\node_modules\node-expat\build\node_expat.vcxproj and see what the linker additional paths is set to.
Maybe try adding to PATH locally to point to %WindowsSdkDir%\lib and %WindowsSdkDir%\common\lib